# How do I check if a username exists in a database within a cgi script?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, cgi

I'm a newbie.

I'm writing a cgi python3 script that will allow a user to log in to a webpage and view database information. The user's username and password are also stored in this database.

My current script successfully exits the script if the password entered does not match the username's password in the database, but it does not exit when the username does not exist. (row[1] contains usernames, row[2] contains passwords)

Why does the script check to see if there is a password match, but no username match? What command script would I want to use to  check for a username match?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

# HTML Content - BEGIN
print("<h1>User Login</h1>")
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
username= data['username'].value    
password= data['password'].value    

#prints form data submission
print("username= " + username)
print("    password= " + password)

#Import Database
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/directory/path/database.db')
c = conn.cursor()


# ***WORK IN PROGRESS***
for row in c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE username = '{username}'"):
    if row[1] != username:
        print("ERROR! No Username!")
        sys.exit()
    if row[2] != password:
        print("ERROR! Wrong password!")
        sys.exit()
#***WORK IN PROGRESS***

#Display personal information
print ("<h1>personal information</h1>")
#HTML CONTENT - END
```

Thank you.

Comment: Think about how many rows `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE username = '{username}'` returns, and then think about how often your loop will be run. Consider `for ... else`.

Comment: You should also **strongly** consider using a parameterized query instead of opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks. http://bobby-tables.com/ etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not very clever, and maybe I don't understand what this command line does: `for row in c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE username = '{username}'"):` I thought it would SELECT the row that equals the username variable. But if the username variable is set to a username that doesn't exist in the database... I'm not understanding how the script continues to run in spite of that.

Comment: Thank you, Shawn. I love that comic strip, and bobby-tables resource helped me understand how to implement server-side data validation.